# Spark- Text File to (String, String)

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

I have a text file which has two tab separated "columns"

```
Japan<tab>Shinjuku
Australia<tab>Melbourne
United States of America<tab>New York
Australia<tab>Canberra
Australia<tab>Sydney
Japan<tab>Tokyo
```

I read this file into an RDD and perform the following operation

```
val myFile = sc.textFile("/user/abc/textfile.txt")
myFile.map(str => str.split("\t")).collect()
```

which results in

```
Array[Array[String]] = Array(Array(Japan,Tokyo), Array(United States of America,Washington DC), Array(Australia,Canberra))
```

But what I want is not `Array[Array[String]]` but `Array[(String, String)]`, so I tried the following

```
myFile.map(str => str.split("\t")).map(arr => (arr[0], arr[1])).collect
```

And got the following error

```
<console>:1: error: identifier expected but integer literal found.
   myFile.map(str => str.split("\t")).map(arr => (arr[0], arr[1])).collect
                                                     ^
```

Could anyone help me with this? What I want is a list of (country, city) so I can perform the following operation

```
ListThatIWant(Country, City)
    .map(a => (a._1, 1))
        .reduceByKey(_+_)
            .reducebyKey((a, b) => if(a>b) a else b)
```

This would give me the country that has the most number of cities in the text filealong with the number of cities/ occurrences in said file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `scala` unlike `java`, elements of array is accessed using `()` not `[]` 
So the correct way is

```
myFile.map(str => str.split("\t")).map(arr => (arr(0), arr(1))).collect
```

Comment: Can't believe I missed that. I tried this but got an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException for trying to access arr(1), which, I **know** exists

Comment: I am surprised with how you are getting `Array[Array[String]]` but since you are getting `Array[Array[String]]` with `myFile.map(str => str.split("\t"))` you should be doing `myFile.map(str => str.split("\t")).map(arr => (arr(0)(0), arr(0)()1)).collect`

Comment: This is what I got `Array[(Char, Char)] = Array((J,a), (A,u), (U,n), (A,u), (A,u), (J,a))`

it took the 1st char of Country and 2nd char of City

Comment: is that the output of `myFile.map(str => str.split("\t"))`?

Comment: No. `myFile.map(str => str.split("\t")).map(arr => (arr(0)(0), arr(0)(1))).collect`

Comment: I'll be damned. `myFile.map(str => str.split("\t")).map(arr => (arr(0), arr(1))).collect` gave the correct output this time. I don't know what went wrong in the first time I tried it

Comment: great to hear that :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the simple example with your data replaced with ;

```
val data = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(
  Seq(
    ("pan;Shinjuku"),
    ("Australia;Melbourne"),
      ("United States of America;New York"),
      ("Australia;Canberra"),
      ("Australia;Sydney"),
      ("Japan;Tokyo")
  ))

val exRDD = data.cache()
val result = exRDD.map(
    rec =>
      (rec.split(";")(0),rec.split(";")(1)))

result.foreach(println)
```

Output:

```
(pan,Shinjuku)
(Australia,Melbourne)
(United States of America,New York)
(Australia,Canberra)
(Australia,Sydney)
(Japan,Tokyo)
```

This should work similar for  as well.
You were trying to access the array with wrong brackets.

Hope this helps